# How do I capture a zoomed UIImageView inside of a Scrollview to crop?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, cgimage

Problem:
Cropping with the image zoomed out is fine.
Cropping with the image zoomed in is showing the image above what is should be.
The yOffset I have in there is because the crop square I want starts below where the scrollview does.

Code:

```
CGRect rect;
float yOffset = 84;
rect.origin.x = floorf([scrollView contentOffset].x * zoomScale);
rect.origin.y = floorf(([scrollView contentOffset].y + yOffset) * zoomScale);
rect.size.width = floorf([scrollView bounds].size.width * zoomScale);
rect.size.height = floorf((320 * zoomScale));

if (rect.size.width > 320) {
    rect.size.width = 320;
}

if (rect.size.height > 320) {
    rect.size.height = 320;
}

CGImageRef cr = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([[imageView image] CGImage], rect);

UIImage *img = imageView.image; //[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cr];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);

// translated rectangle for drawing sub image
CGRect drawRect = CGRectMake(-rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y, 320.0f, 320.0f);
NSLog(@"drawRect: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(drawRect));
NSLog(@"rect: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(rect));

// draw image
[img drawInRect:drawRect];

// grab image
UIImage *cropped = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

CGImageRelease(cr);

[self.delegate imageCropper:self didFinishCroppingWithImage:cropped];
```

What am I doing that is causing the image to get the wrong height when zooming?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
UIImage* imageFromView(UIImage* srcImage, CGRect* rect)
{
    CGImageRef cr = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(srcImage.CGImage, *rect);
    UIImage* cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cr];

    CGImageRelease(cr);
    return cropped;
}
-(void) doneEditing
{
    //Calculate the required area from the scrollview
    CGRect visibleRect;
    float scale = 1.0f/scrollView.zoomScale;
    visibleRect.origin.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x * scale;
    visibleRect.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y * scale;
    visibleRect.size.width = scrollView.bounds.size.width * scale;
    visibleRect.size.height = scrollView.bounds.size.height * scale;


    FinalOutputView* outputView = [[FinalOutputView alloc] initWithNibName:@"FinalOutputView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    outputView.image = imageFromView(imageView.image, &visibleRect);

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:outputView animated:YES];
    [outputView release];
}
```

**Loading Orginal Image:**

[image]

**Zooming Image:**

[image]

**Finally Capturing the Image**

[image]

Comment: Looks pretty good!
I am seeing a green border on the top and bottom of the image.. it looks like the width and size are 240x240 because the scroll view's minimum zoom scale is 1.3.
Testing.. any advice?

Comment: Where in my answer or in your.. if my answer could help you then can you accept it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take screenshot from the whole view of scrollView (after zooming) you can do this:

```
UIImage* image = nil;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.scrollView.contentSize);
{
    //save previous frames
    CGPoint savedContentOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect savedFrame = self.scrollView.frame;
    CGRect imgFrame  = self.imageView.frame;

    //set the frames with current content size
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.contentSize.width, self.scrollView.contentSize.height);
    self.imageView.frame = self.scrollView.frame;

    //render image now :)
    [self.scrollView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    //now set the frames again with old ones :)
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
    self.scrollView.frame = savedFrame;
    self.imageView.frame = imgFrame;
    [self viewForZoomingInScrollView:self.scrollView];
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//get the documents path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
//save file as savedImage.png
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];

//get the png data from image
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
//write it now
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
```