# How do I capture a zoomed UIImageView inside of a Scrollview to crop in Android?

Tags: android, crop, pinchzoom

i have reffered this link [How do I capture a zoomed UIImageView inside of a Scrollview to crop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799805/how-do-i-capture-a-zoomed-uiimageview-inside-of-a-scrollview-to-crop)

i want to do the same thing in android as shown in screenshots below.how can i do it ?

[image: step 1]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried something? or done some research on this. please show us where you currently stand on this.

Comment: @VishwasSharma i have completed this tutorial.http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/07/capture-or-select-from-gallery-and-crop.html . but i want output as above.

Comment: Check this out its really awsome.. [https://github.com/choiboi/android-cropping-example](https://github.com/choiboi/android-cropping-example)

Answer (score 0):

func getZoomedImage() -> UIImage{

```
    //Calculate the required area from the scrollview
    var visibleRect = CGRect()
    let scale: CGFloat = CGFloat(1.0 / scrollViewGallery.zoomScale)
    visibleRect.origin.x = scrollViewGallery.contentOffset.x * scale
    visibleRect.origin.y = scrollViewGallery.contentOffset.y * scale
    visibleRect.size.width = scrollViewGallery.bounds.size.width * scale
    visibleRect.size.height = scrollViewGallery.bounds.size.height * scale
    let cgImg: CGImage? = imgView.image?.cgImage?.cropping(to: visibleRect)
    let croppedImg = UIImage(cgImage: cgImg!)
    return croppedImg
}
```